# my supervisors put me as a last author

Tags: advisor

my supervisors put me as last author in an article submitted to a journal. I had written the majority of the paper and even if it's not my idea, but it's my thesis subject. My supervisor who proposed the idea and corrects the article wants to become the first author and the one who doesn't do anything   wants us to take turns publishing (once me the first author, once him once the other supervisor). I stressed because i'm the one who needs the publications and not them who already have a job

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: There is not nearly enough information to say. You should state your field, and also give more details about who did what. Authorship does not mean just writing the manuscript (or even the code)! The intellectual contribution is what counts. But just throwing out an idea doesn't necessarily rise to the level of an intellectual contribution either -- I have many ideas, but only publish the ones that I make progress on.

Comment: I really begin to realize how much easier student's life would be if all fields adopted math's alphabetical listing for authors.

Comment: It is very rare that success comes from fighting your supervisor.

Comment: Buffy no sense i am not fighting anyone

Comment: @JonCuster I really like how we do it in the biological sciences: first author is the student who did the work, last author is the senior author who supervised the project. There is little to no incentive for senior authors to have anything but last author positions.

Comment: @BryanKrause - that is generally how it is in my field as well, but we sure seem to get a lot of questions about author position anyways from seemingly similar situations. As a mentor of mine pointed out long ago, credit is not a thermodynamically conserved quantity - there is plenty to go around if the work is good.

Comment: @JonCuster True, although I think the first step of ensuring no direct conflict between supervisors and their students resolves the vast majority of argument, leaving just a few edge cases. Since papers often end up known by the "First Author, year" shorthand used in referencing, I don't find alphabetical authorship to be entirely benign either.

Comment: @BryanKrause - Agreed. As is usual with most problems involving people, there is no rigorous, unambiguous, and universally agreed 'solution'...

Comment: @JonCuster Yet another way the mathematicians have simplified things compared to the rest of us ;)

Comment: I tend to look at the titles of the authors - the one with the least probably wrote it...